# Finding PostGIS tables that are missing indexes?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Recently I was looking around in `pg_stat_user_tables` and was surprised to see high numbers of sequential scans on some of my spatial tables.  Sure enough, these tables were missing spatial indexes.

How can I find all tables with an un-indexed geometry column?

Comment: Thanks for the ref to pg_stat_user_tables. It is heartening that someone of your knowledge admits to such mistakes. To the young ones at work that I mentor, I always say: If there is no natural candidate for a primary key, add a serial column. Always define the SRID and geometry type. Always add a spatial index. Because sequence scans might work with a million rows, but, there comes a point..... Do as I say, rather than as I did :D.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tables with missing spatial indexes can be found by querying the system tables:

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     n.nspname, 
     c.relname, 
     c.oid AS relid, 
     a.attname, 
     a.attnum 
   FROM pg_attribute a 
   INNER JOIN pg_class c ON (a.attrelid=c.oid)
   INNER JOIN pg_type t ON (a.atttypid=t.oid)
   INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace=n.oid) 
   WHERE t.typname='geometry' 
   AND   c.relkind='r'
 ) g 
LEFT JOIN pg_index i ON (g.relid = i.indrelid AND g.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)) 
WHERE i IS NULL;
```

Comment: Could it be even better as `WHERE t.typname IN ('geometry', 'geography') AND t.typtype='b'`?  See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6896.

Comment: @user30184 Can you explain the `t.typtype = 'b'` piece of that?

Comment: It is actually useless piece. The code change in GDAL was for dealing with a rare situation when standard PostgreSQL database has a table named "geometry". That has also an entry in pg_type but with typtype='c'. However, if you have PostGIS installed it is not possible to end to such situation. `create table "geometry" (foo text);` gives `ERROR:  type "geometry" already exists HINT:  A relation has an associated type of the same name, so you must use a name that doesn't conflict with any existing type.`

Answer (score 7):

I have created a function which can create automatically all missing indexes. An "simulate" parameter allows to get the list of the missing spatial indexes, but performs not CREATE INDEX

See https://gist.github.com/mdouchin/cfa0e37058bcf102ed490bc59d762042

To get the list of missing indexes, run:

```
SELECT * FROM create_missing_spatial_indexes(True)
```

To create the needed indexes, run:

```
SELECT * FROM create_missing_spatial_indexes()
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM create_missing_spatial_indexes(False)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Great tool.