# Does GeoPandas generate a PostGIS spatial index automatically?

Tags: postgis, geopandas, spatial-index

It is easy to save a GeoPandas dataframe to a PostGIS database using the gdf.to_postgis(...) command. But, it is not clear to me if it automatically generates spatial indices or if these need to be created after the data is loaded into the database?

If it needs to be generated separately, does GeoPandas have a command or do you need to use a different interface to the PostGIS database (e.g., GeoAlchemy, etc)?

Comment: Have you tried using `to_postgis()` and having a look at the resulting table? Seems like the easiest way to find out

Comment: @Joe Be Thanks, but I haven't been able to confirm. I used this solution (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241599/finding-postgis-tables-that-are-missing-indexes) to find all tables that do not have a spatial index but it returns nothing. But, I suspect that they are not there. How do I check?

Comment: You can inspect the created table sql query in pgadmin or alternatively print to your terminal using `pg_dump -t 'schema-name.table-name' --schema-only database-name`