# Dissolve/Union large number (1.2m ) polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, st-union

I am very new to PostGIS. I read that it should work faster than QGIS, so I thought I'd give it a go. I want to completely dissolve a shapefile of 1.2m polygons in the same way as QGIS built in dissolve function works.

This is my current code, which is very basic (filetodissolve is the table):

```
SELECT ST_Union(geom)
FROM filetodissolve f;
```

I've been running this for 1h 30m now and is showing no sign of stopping. Is there any method to speed this up.

Comment: @BERA What code do I need to change in that answer. Just where it says 'table'?

Comment: Yes to the name of your table. With schema, for example **public.yourtablename**

Comment: If you do not need extremely accurate result, try this trick https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222976/cleaning-large-shapefile-using-v-clean-in-order-to-dissolve-features.

Comment: "PostGIS is faster than QGIS" is fake news, or at least sufficiently stark and unnuanced to not address reality.

Comment: @Vince Just looking for a quicker method/a method that actually works. Happy to hear other options.

Comment: @BERA will the code make much difference if most of my polygons overlap?

Comment: do you have an index?

Comment: @IanTurton I have columns gid, fid and geom.

Comment: add a spatial index

Comment: I found a suggestion to use `ST_Buffer(St_Collect(wkb_geometry), 0)` in some old comment. That might also be worth trying. Using `SET work_mem=50000;` for giving more memory was also suggested. If you test with 10000 or 100000 features you will get preliminary results faster.

Comment: @IanTurton how do I add a spatial index?

Comment: Do a research on 'add postgis gist index'

Comment: Before adding a spatial index it might be good to check if it is missing https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241599/finding-postgis-tables-that-are-missing-indexes.

Comment: You haven't talked about the complexity of the polygons to be unioned nor about their connectivity. If processing in one go is too much, you have to break it down in smaller batches. This could be via clusters as shown by Bera, or by using a grid and computing for each quadrant. The more complex as the polygons, the smaller should be the quadrant. Once done, do it again using the previously unioned polygons and a bigger quadrant. But in any cases it is very important to work on nearby geometries

Comment: What version of PostGIS are you using?  The more recent versions of PostGIS/GEOS might provided faster unioning, due to some improvements in the implementation.

Comment: Is there any way you can share the data? I'm curious to see what it looks like, and experiment with the union.

Comment: @dr_jts I don't think I can share the data due to its owners data agreements unfortunately, but thankyou!

Comment: @dr_jts I've only just downloaded PostGIS - its 3.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically the same answer as to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301598/only-union-dissolve-intersecting-or-adjacent-features-to-speed-up-query). It uses [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) to assign each cluster of intersecting/adjacent polygons an id and union based on id:

```
create index table123_index on test.table123 using GIST(geom); --Make sure you have a spatial index

create table test.table123_dissolved as
with clusters
    as (select st_clusterdbscan(geom,0,2) over() cluster_id, geom from test.table123)

select st_union(geom) geom 
from clusters 
where cluster_id is not null --Where there are adjacent polygons that have been assigned a cluster id
group by cluster_id

union

select geom from clusters where cluster_id is null --Polygons that are separate from all others get no cluster id
;
alter table test.table123_dissolved add column id serial;
```

With my test data it finishes in 120 s for 3 million features
[image]

(I canceled Dissolve in QGIS after 20 min/35 % finished.)

Comment: Thankyou. I have been running the code for 18hs now. I have almost 1.3m polygons. The polygon layer is 1.2GB and is the extent of the UK. Will any of this change the speed of the union?

Comment: Do you have large complex multipolygons? Try converting them to single parts using [ST_DUMP](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html). But first try my answer of a subset of your 1.3 million polygons to make sure it is working

Comment: No I did a multipart to single part conversion in QGIS before I loaded the file into PostGIS/pgAgmin4

Comment: I dont know if it makes any difference but you could try [subdividing](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html) the geometries

Comment: This is a good approach if the data contains disjoint clumps of polygons.  Probably won't help if all/many of the polygons are touching, though.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, clustering the spatial index could also be tested - postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/clusterindex.html.